# Converting an blowfish encryption algo from php to python

Tags: php, python, encryption, salt, blowfish

I have this real simple encryption that I used for my site. I am trying to convert all my code from php to python, but I can't figure out how to get python to produce the same output that php did with this code.

```
function myhash($word){
  $salt = "$2a$06$" . substr(sha1($word) , 0, 22) . "$";
  return crypt($word, $salt);
}
```

Seeing as I already have quite a few passwords stored with this encryption, it would be silly to make a new encryption. What to do?

Comment: This module probably has what you want: http://docs.python.org/2/library/crypt.html

Comment: Note that Blowfish is not the same as bcrypt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no blowfish built in. If you can use other modules try [bcrypt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-bcrypt) it does exactly what you need. So the function will be:

```
import hashlib
import brypt
def myhash(word):
    salt = "$2a$06$" + hashlib.sha1(word).hexdigest()[0:22] + "$"
    return bcrypt.hashpw(word, salt)
```